# JWT - Refreshing tokens, and security improvments

Tags: security, facebook-authentication, refresh-token, jwt

I'm developing a new web app with NodeJS and ReactJS and I'm using JWT for authentication. The client side sends a request to /login using axios.post(), the server checks the data entered by the user and returns an access token with an expiration time of 5 minutes and a refresh token. I use Redux to save tokens at the app level state. On next requests, the client side sends back the token to the server.

*My questions are:*

1) Is there a way to open multiple tabs and recover the state of the first tab opened and when the user logs out of a tab, he is logged out of all tabs? (Facebook uses this method)

2) Imagine I connect to the website at a friend's place and when I leave I forget to disconnect, is there a way to disconnect from all the devices when I get home? (Facebook uses that too)

3) Is it possible to automatically delete the tokens in the app level state after X seconds / minutes **only** when tabs are closed and continuously refresh the access token otherwise?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

No answer to your post after 9 days. Too bad, let me help you out.
To get the closest representation of what you want i would use a SameSite Cookie.

They're always on all Tabs and you can also expire them after a period of time.
Cookie will get deleted and you'll be logged out.

In order to work with devices you can use a blacklist on your refresh tokens, although this is against the principles of JWT it is still a possibility.

1. SameSite Cookies spread over all tabs
2. The Cookie can be send with all requests in the header (use strict mode)
3. Deleting the Cookie results in a logout
4. Blacklisting the Refreshtoken JWT will result in a logout of the user aswell.

Would recommend you to read about the SameSite cookie (strict). You'll be surprised because there's not alot of people who know about it.

If i can be of any help feel free to contact me through DM.